# How to organize this layout with overflows?

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm having trouble with some div's position and layout.

The layout I want:
[image: image here]

I want the title to always appear in full and on the right. The subtitle should appear on the left but with any overflow hidden so the title's length always takes precedent.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      .title {height: 25px; text-align:left; width: 300px; border:1px solid red;}
      .subtitle {height: 20px; overflow:hidden; float:left; border: 1px solid blue;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="title">
      Title number 1
      <div class="subtitle">This is subtitle that is longer with even more text</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

At the minute if the subtitle is too long it just hovers underneath.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think it would make more sense to have the title on the left and the subtitle on the right.

Comment: Thanks but I replaced my real data with "title" and "subtitle" for the examples. You're right though, bad example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good time to use [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow).

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sxeu9/

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">Title number 1</div>
    <div class="subtitle">This is subtitle that is longer with even more text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dashed #444;
    padding: 3px;
}
.title {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
.subtitle {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it may not be the perfect solution but it is working... 
it can be a good start.

I positionned the main title over the sub title using the absolute positionneing and hide the subtitle text using a color bakground in the main title div.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
.title {
    height: 25px; 
    width: 300px; 
    position: relative;
}
.maintitle
{
    height: 25px; 
    border:1px solid red;
    font-size: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 10px; /* to give space to the left on the main title */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* to hide the text under it. */
}
.subtitle {
    height: 20px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    max-width: 290px; /* to make sure the sub-title dont fall on two line */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="title">
        <div class="maintitle">
            Title number 1
        </div>  

        <div class="subtitle">
            This is subtitle that is longer with even more text
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/3nCuJ/ (spelled out below)

Specifically, I made the *title* float right, rather than the subtitle floating left.  This makes sure the entire title is visible, on top of the subtitle.  Then in order to make the subtitle clip properly I added an inner div to contain the subtitle text.

If you want the subtitle to stop at a word boundary use this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/3nCuJ/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="title">Title number 1</div>
  <div class="subtitle"><div class="subtitle_inner">This is subtitle that is longer with even more text</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
}
.title {
    height: 23px;
    float: right;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.subtitle {
    height: 23px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.subtitle_inner {
    width: 300px;
}
```